# Adding a class to all checkboxes in cakephp (HABTM)

Tags: cakephp

I have to tables associated with HABTM, and it displays the checkboxes perfectly. The line of code is this:

```
   <?php  echo $this->Form->input('Item.ItemCharacteristic',array('id'=>'item_characteristic','label' =>false,'type'=>'select','multiple'=>'checkbox','options' => $itemCharacteristics,'selected' => $this->Html->value('ItemCharacteristic.ItemCharacteristic')));
  ?>
```

what it displays is this:

```
                       <div class="input select"><input type="hidden" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic]" value="" id="item_characteristic"/>

<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic][]" value="8" id="item_characteristic8" /><label for="item_characteristic8">We-Fii</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic][]" value="9" id="item_characteristic9" /><label for="item_characteristic9">Test1</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic][]" value="10" id="item_characteristic10" /><label for="item_characteristic10">Setting</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic][]" value="11" id="item_characteristic11" /><label for="item_characteristic11">Test4</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic][]" value="13" id="item_characteristic13" /><label for="item_characteristic13">Solari</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic][]" value="15" id="item_characteristic15" /><label for="item_characteristic15">Panorama</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic][]" value="17" id="item_characteristic17" /><label for="item_characteristic17">BlusBrothers</label></div>
</div>
```

so what i want is to add a class within iput element like this:

```
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Item][ItemCharacteristic][]" value="8" id="item_characteristic8" class="element" /><label for="item_characteristic8">We-Fii</label></div>
```

so just to add the class="element" to it..

Any ide??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can placed your class on the field by adding 'class' => 'name' to the array

```
 <?php  echo $this->Form->input('Item.ItemCharacteristic',array('class'=>'mycustomclass' 'id'=>'item_characteristic','label' =>false,'type'=>'select','multiple'=>'checkbox','options' => $itemCharacteristics,'selected' => $this->Html->value('ItemCharacteristic.ItemCharacteristic')));
  ?>
```

I hope it solves your problem

Comment: Thanx @MoyedAnsari for the help. but i manage to solve it, i needed the clas to grab each of the checkboxes and see if at least one was selected, so i put

'before' => "<div id='element'>",'after' => "</div>" 

and it wrap everything within a div with id='element'...